# Время ожидания операции истекло в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Tags: c#, .net, timeout

Есть метод, выполняющий HttpRequest:

```
string GetStringFromWeb(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
            return null;
        string s;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            myRequest.Method = "GET";
            using (HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                    s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                myResponse.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Tools.Logger.Error(e.ToString());
            s = string.Empty;
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Если его вызывать из Desktop-приложения (консольного или wpf), то все нормально работает. Но если вызывать его из windows-службы, то валится ошибка "Время ожидания операции истекло" в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse(). Брандмауэр на машине отключен. Увеличение таймаута запроса и лимита соединений ничего не дало.

В чем может быть причина такого поведения? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю проблема кроется в прокси сервере. Когда ты ранишь из под консоли, то она подтягивает настройки прокси из IE, если оно запущено в виндовом сервисе, то это нужно сделать вручную. Глянь пример кода [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Благодарю. Это действительно помогло.